# Flutter: setState in a callback rebuilds but doesn't fetch fresh data

Tags: flutter, dart

Just getting back into flutter, with the skeleton of a simple v2 project to upgrade and finish.

I create a page as the scaffold body with and pass variables and a callback function. The callback function wraps the update of the variables inside a setState. The same body widget will be used several times with different values passed and then different data loaded.

I've got a demo at https://zapp.run/edit/zy3c060xy3d0?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/menu_list_screen.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: getPage(_pageKey),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
    );
  }
```

getPage simply invokes the widget and returns it. There's a switch but it's essentially lots of this...

```
return MenuListScreen(
            menu: _pageKey,
            email: _email,
            associationId: _associationId,
            callback: menuCallback);
```

The callback needs to work out what the menu item was requesting and I'd expected the setState to trigger the rebuild. I can see that the callback is running, the private variables are changing but the build() never gets called.

```
// C A L L B A C K
  void menuCallback(pageType, url) {
    setState(() {
      if (url.contains('/feed/menu/mobile')) {
        _pageType = 'menu';
        _pageKey = getMenuName(url);
        _pageId = '';
      } else {
        _pageType = pageType;
        _pageKey = '';
        _pageId = getPageId(url);
      }
    });

    print('===');
    print('menuCallback $_pageType $_pageKey $_pageId $url');
    print('===');
  }
```

Put it all together and the class looks like this:

```
class MyTabBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/tabBuilder';

  @override
  State<MyTabBuilder> createState() => _MyTabBuilderState();
}

class _MyTabBuilderState extends State<MyTabBuilder> {
 

  // Used to draw the tabs at the bottom
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _tabs = [
    {'label': 'Home', 'icon': Icons.home},
    {'label': 'Card', 'icon': Icons.credit_card},
    {'label': 'Events', 'icon': Icons.calendar_month},
    {'label': 'News', 'icon': Icons.newspaper},
  ];

  //int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  String _email = "";
  int _associationId = 22;
  String _pageType = 'menu';
  String _pageKey = 'mobilehome';
  String _pageId = ""; // contents_id for when showing a single news/event etc

  

  // listing mobileevents but all the menu options will be handled the same way.
  final List pageReference = [
    
    {'page': 'eventview', 'index': 5, 'tabIndex': 2},
    {'page': 'newsview', 'index': 6, 'tabIndex': 3},
    {'page': 'menu', 'index': 7, 'tabIndex': 0},
  ];

  int get tabIndex {
    final pageDetails =
        pageReference.where((map) => map["page"] == _pageType).toList();
    if (pageDetails.isNotEmpty) {
      return pageDetails[0]['tabIndex'];
    }
    return 7;
  }

  // which tab do we want
  int getPageIndex(pageName) {
    final pageRef =
        pageReference.where((map) => map["page"] == pageName).toList();

    if (pageRef.isNotEmpty) {
      // expected to be able to return pageDetails[0].index but many errors.
      return pageRef[0]['index'];
    }

    // 7 is the home screen but it's never a callback
    return 7;
  }

  String getMenuName(url) {
    const String start = '/feed/menu/';
    const String end = '.json';
    final startIndex = url.indexOf(start);
    final endIndex = url.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

    return url.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
  }

  String getPageId(url) {
    const String start = '/feed/item/';
    const String end = '.json';
    final startIndex = url.indexOf(start);
    final endIndex = url.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

    return url.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
  }

  // C A L L B A C K
  void menuCallback(pageType, url) {
    setState(() {
      if (url.contains('/feed/menu/mobile')) {
        _pageType = 'menu';
        _pageKey = getMenuName(url);
        _pageId = '';
      } else {
        _pageType = pageType;
        _pageKey = '';
        _pageId = getPageId(url);
      }
    });

    //int index = getPageIndex(pageType);
    print('===');
    print('menuCallback $_pageType $_pageKey $_pageId $url');
    print('===');
  }

 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> get _getBottomNavigationBarItems {
    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> output = [];

    for (var element in _tabs) {
      print("bottom tab bar item: ${element['label']}");

      output.add(
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(element['icon'] as IconData),
          label: (element['label'] as String),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      );
    }

    return output;
  }

  Widget getPage(pageKey) {
    int idx = getPageIndex(pageKey);
    print('getPage: $pageKey, $idx');

    switch (idx) {
      
      case 0:
      case 7:
      default:
        print('=-=-=-=-=');
        print('$_pageType $_pageKey $_pageId');
        print('=-=-=-=-=');
        return MenuListScreen(
            menu: _pageKey,
            email: _email,
            associationId: _associationId,
            callback: menuCallback);
    }
  }

  BottomNavigationBar get bottomNavBar => BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _getBottomNavigationBarItems,
      currentIndex: tabIndex,
      elevation: 10.0,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _pageKey = _pageKey;
          // this will be ignored by news and events but overrides any existing
          // choices made by the user.
          _pageId = '';
        });
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

    print('build: $_pageKey');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: getPage(_pageKey),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
    );
  }
}
```

On the widget that's being called there's a refresh function and when that is invoked the body does rebuild and with the new information.

```
void doRefresh() {
    menuList =
        NetworkMenuList(menu: widget.menu, email: widget.email).refreshMenuList();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

The full MenuList is

```
class MenuListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuListScreen(
      {Key? key,
      required this.menu,
      required this.email,
      required this.associationId,
      required this.callback})
      : super(key: key);
  final String menu;
  final String email;
  final int associationId;
  final Function callback;

  static const routeName = '/menuList';

  @override
  State<MenuListScreen> createState() => _HomeListScreenState();
}

class _HomeListScreenState extends State<MenuListScreen> {
  late Future<MenuListModel> menuList =
      NetworkMenuList(menu: widget.menu, email: widget.email).getMenuList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("=*=*=*=*=*=*= init ${widget.menu}");
  }

  void doRefresh() {
    menuList =
        NetworkMenuList(menu: widget.menu, email: widget.email).refreshMenuList();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

    return RefreshIndicator(
      color: Colors.green,
      onRefresh: () async {
        return doRefresh();
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
          FutureBuilder<MenuListModel>(
              future: menuList,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {

                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.menu.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return MenuCard(
                              menuRow: snapshot.data!.menu[index],
                              callback: widget.callback);
                        }),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I've added more debugging and I can see that the widgets rebuild BUT the call to get the data doesn't run and it uses the old value. I'm creating a new instance of the screen, I'd expect the data to have to run. How do I force it?

Comment: Unclear from your code snippets... are you invoking the setState within the State class of your main widget?

Comment: Yes, I'll try and update my initial post to be clearer, wanted to avoid adding all the extra functions but that may not have been helpful.